# Turbulence and the symmetries of Navier-Stokes

Tags: symmetry, navier-stokes, turbulence

I am reading the book "Turbulence - The Legacy of A.N. Kolmogorov" by Frisch. He begins the book by introducing the different stages of fluid motion when the Reynolds number increases. In particular these stages are illustrated with the example of a uniform flow passing a cylinder. It is describes how the symmetries of the setup are respecting the symmetries of Navier-Stokes equation and how this can be observed in the fluid motion for smaller Reynolds numbers.

Now as the Reynolds number increases we can observe how these symmetries are spontaneously broken. My question is, whether the following explanation is correct?

*If the experimental setup was indeed perfectly symmetrical (including a perfectly uniform external flow), we would not observe any break of symmetry, independently of the Reynolds number. The reason for the observed break of symmetry in the flow, is because the symmetries of the setup are not perfect. The chaotic nature of the underlying dynamical system is the reason for why these small violations of symmetry in the setup lead to turbulence.*

Comment: I think you are right. This animation of the unsteady flow behind the cylinder was made by numerically solving the Navier-Stokes with $Re = 100$ with a slight symmetry breaking. But when the symmetry was not broken, then a stationary solution can be obtained up to $Re = 10000$ - https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064

Comment: @AlexTrounev Any Reynolds number above 400 won't lead to physical correct results on that grid. First of all your amount of cells is not sufficient for a direct numerical simulation as you have to resolve everything down to the Kolmogorov scale which scales with $N \propto Re^\frac{3 d}{4}$ (where d is the number of dimensions of your simulation and thus requires significantly more than 2000 cells. Secondly the flow around the cylinder is highly three-dimensional for any Reynolds number above 400 which means you would have to perform a 3D simulation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev For Reynolds numbers higher than 2000 a turbulent flow will also form turbulent structures before the cylinder and would have to make sure that these form either already imposing a turbulent profile at the inlet or increase the run-in distance. Anyways the distance between the inlet and the cylinder is too short: The fluid is slowed down locally in front of the cylinder, forming a high-pressure-bubble for any non-creeping flows that will not take a correct form if you enforce a certain fluid velocity at an inlet that is placed too close.

Comment: In numerical simulations you will have a round-off error that would be sufficient to trigger instabilities and discretisation artifacts (leading discretisation errors of dispersive or dissipative nature). In particular dissipative errors dampen oscillations and therefore instabilities.

Comment: @2b-t It describes the standard test for laminar flows from https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MEK4300/v14/undervisningsmateriale/schaeferturek1996.pdf , which has nothing to do with the Kolmogorov scale for developed turbulent flows.

Comment: @AlexTrounev You mentioned a $Re = 10000$ - that is highly turbulent for channel flow as well as for the flow around a cylinder. While the boundary layer stays laminar until $Re \approx 10^6$ the vortex street starts to transition into turbulence around $Re \gtrsim 150$. http://www.thermopedia.com/content/5637/TUBES_CROSSFLOW_OVER_FIG2.gif At any number higher than $300$ or $400$ the flow will lose its depth symmetry: https://www.tafsm.org/PROJ/BFM/3dcyl.gif And even for laminar flow you would have to resolve the boundary layer correctly (e.g. compare to Blasius solution for a flat plate).

Comment: @2b-t 1) Do not confuse 2D and 3D. 2) What can you say on the subject?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't get your point. You can't calculate something 2D that is actually 3D. Solving Navier-Stokes 2D is only possible if you have a good reason to do so, e.g. a exact symmetry, else it is inherently three-dimensional. I just pointed out that using your solver to calculate $Re = 10 000$ like this will give not give you anything physical.

Comment: @2b-t 1) I have a good reason to calculate 2D flow; 2) Can you collect all your comments in one answer to the paul's question?

Comment: @AlexTrounev For $Re = 100$ you have a good one, for $Re = 10 000$ you do not have a reason to do so, not with this method and resolution. But you are right, the discussion does not help answering his question. I personally think as well that Paul's remark is correct but I only wanted to point out that numerical simulations are not a solid argument as they contain several errors (round-off due to limited floating point precision, spatial and temporal discretisation with effects on the geometry as well as simulated equations of motions, mass-gain with non-conservative schemes, ...) themselves.